# How shall i run execute two git commands in single gradle task

Tags: gradle

I have two commands to initialize and update the git submodule how can i run it together. here are the tasks.

```
task gitSubModuleInit(type: Exec) {
    description 'Initialize  the git submodule'
    commandLine "git", "submodule", "init"
}

task gitSubModuleUpdate(type: Exec) {
    description 'Update the git submodule'
    commandLine "git", "submodule", "update"
}
```

Two Questions

1) How can i run the git submodule init and update tasks in single task?
2) Is it possible to link these tasks as a part of build task? so when ever i build it would automatically update the submodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure:

```
task gitSubModuleInit(type: Exec) {
    description 'Initialize  the git submodule'
    commandLine "git", "submodule", "init"
}

task gitSubModuleUpdate(type: Exec, dependsOn: gitSubModuleInit) {
    description 'Update the git submodule'
    commandLine "git", "submodule", "update"
}

<taskThatNeeds the files, probably compileJava>.dependsOn gitSubModuleUpdate
```

Comment: is it possible to put the init and update tasks into a single task?